# View Pager destroy items when i scroll down

Tags: java, android, slider

I am using Image slider inside recycler View Items, each item have view pager and its own image slider, After loading all items in recycler view. first item display image slider inside its view pager, Then i scroll down to other items may be to item 10 or 11 and then i scroll up to first item then view pager destroy all items or fragments inside it and no image has been displayed now . please give me solution for this, my adapter code . Can't User FragmentStatePagerAdapter because not have access to Fragment Manager

```
    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


   ArrayList<ImageInfo> allImages=new ArrayList<>();




    private ViewPagerAdapter(ArrayList<ImageInfo> allImages){
        this.allImages = allImages;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return allImages.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(myContext).inflate(R.layout.fragment_big_row_image, container, false);

        ImageView imageListing = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageListing);


        //MH: Loading Images in slider
        if(allImages.get(position).csImageFull.length()>0)
        {
            CommonMethods.ShowImage(myContext, imageListing, allImages.get(position).csImageFull);

        }
        else
        {
            CommonMethods.ShowImage(myContext, imageListing, allImages.get(position).csImageMedium);

        }

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
       // ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
       // instantiateItem(container,position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}

   /*****************************************************************************************************/
```

Comment: have you used adapter.notifydatasetchanged() ??

Comment: i am not changing dataset, it automatically destroys dataset when i scroll down

Comment: can you post the logcat , what is the error

Comment: it does not show any error , just destroyItem method is called

Answer (score 0):

Set off screen pages in your viewpager. Offscreen page limit defines how many pages you want to keep in memory in your view pager. Set this number to your desired page count.

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

Here view pager will keep last visited 2 pages in memory and won't destroy them.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code:

```
public class SliderPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String> images;

    public SliderPagerAdapter(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_slider, container, false);
        ImageView allImages = null;

      /MH: Loading Images in slider
        if(images.get(position).csImageFull.length()>0)
        {
            CommonMethods.ShowImage(myContext, imageListing, allImages.get(position).csImageFull);

        }
        else
        {
            CommonMethods.ShowImage(myContext, allImages, images.get(position).csImageMedium);

        }

        container.addView(itemView);



        return view;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<String> images) {
        this.images = images;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images == null ? 0 : images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object obj) {
        return view == obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

Call method setData from activity and set image array.

```
Adapter.setData(yourData);
```